# How do i pass a predicate function as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, predicate, functor, c++98

I have a simple predicate:

```cpp
class less_than
{
  int  x;

public:
  less_than(int i):
    x(i)
  {
  }

  bool  operator()(int i) const
  {
    return i < x;
  }
};
```

I have a container which looks like this:

```cpp
my_containers<std::list<int>, less_than, int> myCont(list_1, list_2, less_than(11));
```

- The first parameter says what's the type of the `list_1` and `list_2`.
- The second parameter says the name of the predicate.
- The third parameter says what's the item type of the `list_1` and `list_2`.

I tried to create my template like this:

```cpp
template<class Type, class Predicate, class Item_Stored>
class my_containers
{
public:
  my_containers(Type &tar_1, Type &tar_2, Predicate felt)
  {
    ItemList_1 = tar_1;
    ItemList_2 = tar_2;
    predIcate  = felt;
  }

  my_containers & insert(const Item_Stored put_in)
  {
    if (!predIcate.operator()(put_in))
    {
      ItemList_1.insert(ItemList_1.end(), put_in);
    }
    else
    {
      ItemList_2.insert(ItemList_2.end(), put_in);
    }

    return *this;
  }

private:
  Type       ItemList_1;
  Type       ItemList_2;
  Predicate  predIcate;
};
```

Every time i use `.insert(x)`, it should add the `x` to the first list if it is less than the given `less_than::x` otherwise into the other list but it gives me this error:

```c
Error   C2512   'less_than': no appropriate default constructor available
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: ot: `predIcate.operator()(put_in)` is the same as `predicate(put_in)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor demands the default constructor of each member. use ***member initializer list*** instead.

```cpp
    my_containers(Type& tar_1, Type& tar_2, Predicate felt)
        :ItemList_1(tar_1), ItemList_2(tar_2), predIcate(felt){}
```

refer to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

- Try to define your constructors always be `explicit`.
- Then `x.operator()()` is same as `x()`.
- And always use Member Initialization List:

```cpp
struct A
{
  double m_var;

  A(const double var) : m_var(var) {}
};
```

**Not**:

```cpp
struct A
{
  double m_var;

  A(const double var) 
  { 
    m_var = var;
  }
};
```

And your problem will be solved. Because your `less_than` class don't have any default constructor and in your `my_container` constructor you must explicitly initialize the `predIcate` member other wise it's try to initialize with default constructor which don't have it and fail in compile.

So you need to initialize `predIcate` in Member initialize list or define a default constructor for `less_than` class.